# Rails redirects back again to the same page after submitting form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

[Updated question, please see the latter half]

I'm bulding a simple web application that has a simple sign-up/login form.
The system I want to have is

- You put your name and keyword in the form.(at /save_user.html)
- Press the "confirm" link
- Check if the username is used or not. true -> update, false -> register
- redirect to /goodbye.html (controller)

Now I am testing with a new username/keyword set every time.
the problem is, that the final output is `/save_update` , and ends up with an error that says no parameters are givin. (Of course no parameters are givin)

I's there something I can do for this? thankyou!

Controller

```
#
# Register user
#
def save_user
  point_id = session[:point_id]
  @point = Point.find(point_id)
end

def save_update
  username = params[:user][:name]
  keyword = params[:user][:key]
  point_id = session[:point_id]
  #
  # if username exists, match password.
  # if not, create new.
  #
  user = User.find_by_username(username)
  if user
    if user.keyword == Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(user.salt + keyword)
      # User exists!
      render text: 'Matched!'
    else
      # keyword is wrong
      render text:"keyword is wrong.."
    end
  else
    # save new user!
    user = User.create(salt:SecureRandom.hex(4))
    user.update(
        username:username,
        keyword:Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(user.salt + keyword)
    )
    point = Point.find(point_id)
    point.update(:user_id => user.id)

    return redirect_to action: :goodbye
  end
end

def goodbye
  # goodbye.html.erb exists
  point_id = session[:point_id]
  point = Point.find(point_id)
  @username = User.find(point.user_id).username
end
```

View (save_user.html.erb)

```
<%= form_tag({action: :save_update}, {name: :user_info, method: :post}) do -%>
    <p>Username(英数字)：
      <%= text_field_tag("user[name]", "", options:{ id:'user_name' }) %></p>
    <p>Keyword(英数字)　　：
      <%= text_field_tag("user[key]", "", options:{ id:'user_key' }) %></p>
    <br>
    <!-- see diagnose2_helper.rb! ↓ -->
    <%= submit_link_tag(name = "confirm", form_id = "user_info", action="save_update") %>
<% end %>
```

Helper

```
def submit_link_tag(name = "submit", form_id, action)#, options = {})
  content_tag( :a, name, { "href" => "./#{action}", "onclick" => "document.#{form_id}.submit();"})
end
```

---

---

I now realized two problems with my code, but though it changed it, it didn't solve it.

1. In save_user.html.erb, I had an `form_tag({action: :save_update} ...`, and also a `submit_link_tag` with the same action in it. So it was calling the `save_upate` action twice.
2. Even when I deleted the `{action: :save_update}`, I've got the same error, but this time it seems so because the submit_link doesn't send any Hash.

I will re-think my code from scratch now, but if someone has any ideas about this issue, thanks, it'll be very helpful.

Comment: use if user......rather than if- if (user = User.find_by_username(username)) to check if user is present..

Comment: If you are not using form object, then the parameters won't be wrapped with **user** as key eg: (`"user" => {"name" => "some_name", "key" => "some_key"}....`), so using `params[:user][:name]` will give you nil result. So use `params[:name]` directly instead

Comment: @Milind Thank you, but is this just about Ruby style guidline? I fixed it though:)

Comment: @Abhi I think that `text_field_tag("user[name]"...` makes a hash of `user:{name:"some_name", key:"some_key"}` , just to test, I inserted a `p params[:user][:name]` and a `p params[:name]` , and I've got `"some_name"` and `nil` in that order.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
redirect_to action: :goodbye
```

not

```
return redirect_to action: :goodbye
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use

```
 redirect_to :back
```

Comment: thanks, but the final result was same. It did
POST save_update
GET save_update
GET save_user
GET save_update
and ended with a `NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)` again.

Comment: May be you are missing some parameters that need to be passed to that method just check once...